# How to Maintain Application Insights Live Metrics with Serilog and Local File Logging

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

I am currently working on a .NET project where I need to implement logging both to Azure Application Insights and a local file. For this, I am using Serilog along with the Serilog.ApplicationInsights.Sink package. My setup allows me to log effectively to both destinations. However, I am facing a challenge with the Application Insights integration.

Issue:
After integrating Serilog, the live metrics trace feature in Application Insights seems to be disrupted. Specifically, I am no longer seeing the sample telemetry data in the live metrics stream. This is a crucial feature for our real-time monitoring needs.

Question:
How can I configure Serilog so that it logs to a local file without interfering with the live metrics functionality of Application Insights? Are there any specific settings or configurations within Serilog or Application Insights that I should be aware of to achieve this dual logging capability while retaining full functionality?

What I've Tried:

Standard integration of Serilog with Serilog.ApplicationInsights.Sink.
Ensuring Application Insights is correctly configured for live metrics.
I would greatly appreciate any insights, code snippets, or configuration examples that the community can provide to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights` on an Azure Web App, and I could view live metrics from the Application Insights dashboard.
Did you specified the `telemetryConverter` attribute in the sink configuration?

This is how I configured the sink in the configuration:

- Defined a log with name `ApplicationInsights`.
- Added argument `connectionString` with a value like `InstrumentationKey=<your-key>;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-5.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/`.
  In my case I refer to west europ region, change with the one that you are using.
- Added argument `telemetryConverter` with value `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights`.
  Probably this setting is

On Azure the configuration is provided by the configuration section of the Web App with the following keys: `Serilog__WriteTo__2__Name`, `Serilog__WriteTo__2__Args__connectionString`, `Serilog__WriteTo__2__Args__telemetryConverter`.

Note that the number specified after the `__WriteTo__` refer to the position in the `WriteTo` array in the configuration.

In addition I also specified the keys for `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` in the configuration as:

- `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`: simply the key
- `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`: same as `Serilog__WriteTo__2__Args__connectionString` with `InstrumentationKey`, `IngestionEndpoint` and `LiveEndpoint`

In addition there is alist of the packages that I included in my project:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
```

I wish this could help you.

Comment: I have the following config, but still didn't work{
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=key;IngestionEndpoint=https://endp.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://endp.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }

Comment: Did you include `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights` in the `Using` array?  
I noted that in the `ingestionEndpoint`  `https://` is missing but I think it is only a typo.